# 301 redirect urls with trailing slash to urls without trailing slash web2py

Tags: web2py

Testing a web2py app revealed that it might be penalised by google containing duplicate content since www.xyz.com/about.html and www.xyz.com/about.html/ have the same content.
I would like to 301 redirect urls with trailing slashes to urls without trailing slashes.
How do I do that with web2py?
Are there better ways than 301 redirecting for the above purpose?

Many thanks!

Comment: Many thanks Anthony - works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Early in the first model file, you can do:

```
if request.url and len(request.url) > 1 and request.url.endswith('/'):
    redirect(URL(args=request.args, vars=request.get_vars))
```

`request.url` is equivalent to `request.env.path_info` (i.e., it includes the originally requested full URL path without the query string), so, the above will even redirect `/some/path/?var=value` to `/some/path?var=value`.

Alternatively, you could configure your web server (e.g., Nginx) to handle the redirects.

Comment: I realized that the above causes a problem with the index-page of the app. On Firefox it throws an error saying the page did not redirect properly. For other pages of the app, the redirect works fine (i.e. about/ to about).

Comment: Right -- if you request just the host with no path, the browser appends '/', so you end up with an infinite redirect. I updated the answer to handle that case.